# Bullet debug drawer with OpenGL

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, opengl, bullet

I have been fiddling around with bullet for a bit and I now want to draw debug.
I have an opengl world with working bullet physics and everything.

What I have tried is this:
I have created a class GLDebugDrawer like this:

```
#include "LinearMath/btIDebugDraw.h"

class GLDebugDrawer : public btIDebugDraw
{
   int m_debugMode;

public:

   GLDebugDrawer();
   virtual ~GLDebugDrawer();

   virtual void   drawLine(const btVector3& from, const btVector3& to, const btVector3& fromColor, const btVector3& toColor);

   virtual void   drawLine(const btVector3& from, const btVector3& to, const btVector3& color);

   virtual void   drawSphere(const btVector3& p, btScalar radius, const btVector3& color);

   virtual void   drawTriangle(const btVector3& a, const btVector3& b, const btVector3& c, const btVector3& color, btScalar alpha);

   virtual void   drawContactPoint(const btVector3& PointOnB, const btVector3& normalOnB, btScalar distance, int lifeTime, const btVector3& color);

   virtual void   reportErrorWarning(const char* warningString);

   virtual void   draw3dText(const btVector3& location, const char* textString);

   virtual void   setDebugMode(int debugMode);

   virtual int      getDebugMode() const { return m_debugMode; }

};
```

Then in the game I include this header and create a instance of it.

Where I initialize the bt world, I set the debug draw type like this:

```
debugDraw->DBG_DrawWireframe; // this breaks when I run the app
debugDraw->setDebugMode(btIDebugDraw::DBG_DrawWireframe); // so does this
debugDraw->setDebugMode(1); // this doesn't
```

I then set the debug to the bullet world like this:

```
bt_dynamicsWorld->setDebugDrawer(debugDraw);
```

And finally, I render the debug draw after I render the bullet bodies like this:

```
bt_dynamicsWorld->debugDrawWorld();
```

There must be something that I am missing as I am not getting any wireframes or anything when running.

Comment: I know this is an old message, but it popped up to the top when I searched.  Did you happen to actually implement any of those methods in your GLDebugDrawer class?

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple set of code available at http://sio2interactive.forumotion.net/t599-enabling-bullet-debug-draw-code-included  which should be relatively straightforward to use to modify your code, looks like you may need to change `bt_dynamicsWorld->setDebugDrawer(debugDraw);` to `bt_dynamicsWorld->setDebugDrawer(&debugDraw);` (not sure though as don't know how you have your framework setup.

Comment: hey there. Thanks for the reply. I have looked at that article and followed it, but I am still not getting anything through. If I do `bt_dynamicsWorld->setDebugDrawer(&debugDraw);` I get this: `cannot convert argument 1 from 'GLDebugDrawer **' to 'btIDebugDraw *'`.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to pass a reference of your instantiated class to the `setDebugDrawer` function like this:

```
GLDebugDrawer MyDrawer;
...
bt_dynamicsWorld->setDebugDrawer(&MyDrawer);
```

Second, and equally as important, you must define the virtual functions laid out in your `GLDebugDrawer` class so that when bullet calls one of these functions to draw debugging information your debug drawer can actually draw something to the screen.